# R-How to split list of row value into new column value against ID

Tags: r

I'm new to r programming, i need to achieve below desire output can you please help me.
dataframe:

```
ID      Name                      
 1      null                      
 2      list(A = 10, B = 20)      
 2      list(G = 4, U = 2)        
 3      null                      
 3      null                      
 4      list(A = 7, B = 10)
```

Desired Output will be,

```
ID      Measure                   Measure.A   Measure.B                 
 1      null                      null          null                   
 2      list(A = 10, B = 20)      10             20                    
 2      list(A = 4, B = 2)         4              2                     
 3      null                       null          null                  
 3      null                       null          null                  
 4      list(A = 7, B = 10)        7              10
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have NA instead of `NULL` elements in a `data.frame`.  Loop through the 'Name' column (assuming it is a `list` with nested `list` elements), `replace` the `NULL` (assuming it is real NULL and not a character string `"null"`) with NA and `rbind` the elements using `do.call`.  Assign the output to create two new columns in 'df1'

```
df1[c("Measure.A", "Measure.B")] <- unlist(do.call(rbind, 
            lapply(df1$Name, function(x) replace(x, is.null(x), NA))))

names(df1)[2] <- "Measure"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4), Name = structure(list(
NULL, structure(list(A = 10, B = 20), .Names = c("A", "B"
)), structure(list(G = 4, U = 2), .Names = c("G", "U")), 
NULL, NULL, structure(list(A = 7, B = 10), .Names = c("A", 
"B"))), class = "AsIs")), .Names = c("ID", "Name"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for you are instance response ,But I'm getting Below issues .please help me.     Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: @muthukutty  Based on the data in my post, it is working fine

Comment: But Sir I'm using almost thousands of record,That scenario it will not work. please guide me...

Comment: @muthukutty  If this works on 7 records, it should also work for 1000s of record.  I am assuming the structure of the data is similar.  You haven't shown any dput output in your post as Sotos suggested.  So we are just guessing to help you

Comment: Thanks for suggestion ,you right the actual problem is list of variable is increased after certain row . can you please help me how to add a column dynamically based on List of variables increses .Ex:df1[c("Measure.A", "Measure.B,Measure.C,Measure.D,etc")]